# PrimeFaces rewrite PDF path to show in new window

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 with JSF.If I press commandLink I send my pdf path to javascript function and it will open the file in  new window.My doubt is it open to the new window with show the full pdf path. How to rewrite or just show file name?

```
<p:commandLink value="clickMe" onClick="linkFile(myfilePath)"/>

function linkFile(url)
{
   window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use something like this, it should do the trick:

```
<p:commandButton id="openDoc" ajax="false" icon="fa fa-external-link" onclick="target='_blank'">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{myBean.download(doc.id)}" contentDisposition="inline" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The `myBean.download(doc.id)`  should return the PDF as `StreamedContent`.
After clicking on the `commandbutton` a new tab should open displaying the PDF.
The shown url shoud remain the same